# Iterating through a column of lists and appending other columns based on list order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
cats = {'lesson_name': {0: 'Mutt',
  1: 'Ragdoll',
  2: 'Black',
  3: 'Calico',
  4: 'Tortoise',
  5: 'Mainecoon'},
 'tag_list': {0: ['Orange', 'Black', 'White'],
  1: ['Grey', 'White'],
  2: ['Black','Brown'],
  3: ['Orange','Grey','White'],
  4: ['Orange', 'Brown','White'],
  5: ['Grey','White']},
 'Orange': {0: '',
  1: '',
  2: '',
  3: '',
  4: '',
  5: ''},
 'Black': {0: '',
  1: '',
  2: '',
  3: '',
  4: '',
  5: ''},
 'White': {0: '',
  1: '',
  2: '',
  3: '',
  4: '',
  5: ''},
 'Grey': {0: '',
  1: '',
  2: '',
  3: '',
  4: '',
  5: ''},
 'Brown': {0: '',
  1: '',
  2: '',
  3: '',
  4: '',
  5: ''}}

cats_frame = pd.DataFrame(cats)
```

I am trying to make a function to append the colour columns (orange, black, white, grey, brown) based on the order of the list in the "tag_list" column. For example, if 'Orange' is the first colour in the tag_list, I want that row to have a '1' in the Orange column, if the second colour in the list is 'Black', I want that row to have a '2' in the Black column.

I was thinking of making a function for every colour and have tried:

```
def black(df):
        
    for (df['tag_list'],j) in df.iteritems():
        
        if [j][0] == 'Black':
            return 1
        
        if [j][1] == 'Black':
            return 2
        
        if [j][2] == 'Black':
            return 3

        else:
            return 0
        
cats_frame['Black'] = cats_frame.apply(black,1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will caveat this by saying there are probably more efficient ways to do this, but unless your dataframe is massive this is a reasonable way to accomplish it using `df.iterrows()`

```
#iterate over the rows
for idx, cols in cats_frame.iterrows():
    #iterate over the columns containing color names
    for c in cats_frame.columns[2:]:
        #Check whether the column name appears in the list
        if c in cols['tag_list']:
            #If it does, find the index in the list, add 1 due to zero-indexing, and assign the value
            cols[c]=cols['tag_list'].index(c)+1
        else:
            #otherwise, add 0
            cols[c]=0

    lesson_name tag_list                Orange  Black   White   Grey    Brown
0   Mutt        [Orange, Black, White]  1       2       3       0       0
1   Ragdoll     [Grey, White]           0       0       2       1       0
2   Black       [Black, Brown]          0       1       0       0       2
3   Calico      [Orange, Grey, White]   1       0       3       2       0
4   Tortoise    [Orange, Brown, White]  1       0       3       0       2
5   Mainecoon   [Grey, White]           0       0       2       1       0
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way of solving the problem:

```
tag = pd.DataFrame(cats_frame['tag_list'].tolist())
tag_order = tag.stack().reset_index(level=1)\
               .set_index(0, append=True)['level_1'].add(1).unstack(fill_value=0)

cats_frame.update(tag_order)
```

**Details:**

```
>>> tag

        0      1      2
0  Orange  Black  White
1    Grey  White   None
2   Black  Brown   None
3  Orange   Grey  White
4  Orange  Brown  White
5    Grey  White   None

>> tag_order

0  Black  Brown  Grey  Orange  White
0      2      0     0       1      3
1      0      0     1       0      2
2      1      2     0       0      0
3      0      0     2       1      3
4      0      2     0       1      3
5      0      0     1       0      2

>> cats_frame

  lesson_name                tag_list Orange Black White Grey Brown
0        Mutt  [Orange, Black, White]      1     2     3    0     0
1     Ragdoll           [Grey, White]      0     0     2    1     0
2       Black          [Black, Brown]      0     1     0    0     2
3      Calico   [Orange, Grey, White]      1     0     3    2     0
4    Tortoise  [Orange, Brown, White]      1     0     3    0     2
5   Mainecoon           [Grey, White]      0     0     2    1     0
```

Comment: chaining those operations are amazing! but this seems to be slower than other for-based answers, why do you think? (quick benchmark gave 777 and 1250 microsec for others, 4630 for this)

Comment: Thanks @MustafaAydın :) IMHO this should be more efficient in terms of performance when dealing with larger dataset for smaller ones going with the for loop would be okay. Try increasing the size dataframe and then check the performance and let me know if you find any difference.

Comment: @MustafaAydın You can try recreating a larger dataframe with `cats_frame = pd.concat([cats_frame]*10000, ignore_index=True)` then you can use lets say `timeit` to check the performance.

Comment: Indeed, 119 **ms** vs 8.42 **s** and 12.2 **s**! thanks

Answer (score 1):

```py
# i holds index e.g. 1; a_list is for example [Grey, White] in the second turn
for i, a_list in enumerate(cats_frame.tag_list):
    # j becomes the index number (starting at 1), color becomes e.g. "Grey"
    for j, color in enumerate(a_list, start=1):
        # put numbers according to tag list to the position
        # where i points to the row and color points to the column
        cats_frame.loc[i, color] = str(j)
```

Then

```
  lesson_name                tag_list Orange Black White Grey Brown
0        Mutt  [Orange, Black, White]      1     2     3
1     Ragdoll           [Grey, White]                  2    1
2       Black          [Black, Brown]            1                2
3      Calico   [Orange, Grey, White]      1           3    2
4    Tortoise  [Orange, Brown, White]      1           3          2
5   Mainecoon           [Grey, White]                  2    1
```